# Random cells appear in dynamically generated table IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, wicket

I am using Wicket (6.4.0 but it has been happening since we were using 1.4) to generate dynamically sized tables using wicket's ListView component (I have also experienced this with DataView and others).  Ocassionally the table will display with an extra cell that bumps the other cells out of the correct column, but just for one row!  It is hard to explain so please see the image below:

[image]

The generated html doesn't show any extra td elements being generated.
Does anyone know what is causing this, or even better how to avoid it?

EDIT:
This issue was caused by an IE9 & IE10 bug that balks at spaces between `</td>` and the next `<td>` so I changed:

```
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td wicket:id="..."/>
         <td wicket:id="..."/>
       </tr>
     <table>
```

to:

```
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td wicket:id="...">
         </td><td wicket:id="..."/>
       </tr>
     <table>
```

and the mystery cells stopped appearing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen similar "artifacts" when divs or spans, etc got into the table -> tr -> td hierarchy. Make sure you don't have any such tags between these three tags, use setRenderBodyOnly(true) on your listitems if the ListView is added to a div or span tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am, in-fact, using divs in my table/tr/td heirarchy in order to create nested ListViews that have matching column alignment.  (in my example, the light blue rows are one listView, while the grey&white rows are the sub-listView.  This is done to display values by team, & by department.)  Do you know of a better way to do this?

Comment: If the div tags are attached to the actual ListView components then you can make wicket not render the div tag by calling setRenderBodyOnly(true) on the item component in the populateItem method inside ListView.

Comment: I tried all sorts of combinations of #setRenderBodyOnly(true) with limited success.  The final solution ended up being due to an IE9 bug where adjacent <td> columns cannot have any spaces between them when being rerendered via Ajax. See my edited question above for a better description.

Comment: Cool, did not know about that bug, but makes sense.

Comment: I had the same problem.  There were HTML comments between our dynamically generated TD's.  The </TD>, the <!-- -->, and the next <TD> were all on separate lines (for good readability).  99.9% of the time, it worked fine, but every now and then, IE would add an extra blank cell.  I fixed the problem just like OnesAndZeros so that it looked like "...</TD><!-- comment --><TD>..." and it worked fine.